# How to convert string type to timestamp in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am struggling to convert the string type based into timestamp as below.

```
+--------------------+
|              mydate|
+--------------------+
|26/Feb/2023:13:58:40|
|26/Feb/2023:13:30:33|
|26/Feb/2023:13:52:50|
|26/Feb/2023:13:47:09|
|26/Feb/2023:13:30:33|
|26/Feb/2023:13:14:28|
|26/Feb/2023:13:11:42|
|26/Feb/2023:13:34:03|
|26/Feb/2023:13:50:43|
|26/Feb/2023:13:10:47|
|26/Feb/2023:13:28:09|
|26/Feb/2023:13:30:16|
|26/Feb/2023:13:19:07|
|26/Feb/2023:13:30:24|
|26/Feb/2023:13:30:16|
|26/Feb/2023:13:05:37|
|26/Feb/2023:13:09:24|
|26/Feb/2023:13:24:18|
|26/Feb/2023:13:49:13|
|26/Feb/2023:13:56:40|
+--------------------+
```

I have the string type as below and I found the some codes that makes it converted to the time stamp. My pyspark code is as below.

```
wt.select('mydate').show()
wt.select(to_timestamp(lit('mydate'),"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss")).show()
```

But the results are empty even though I tried many times.

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|to_timestamp('mydate', 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss')|
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
|                                          null|
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: `lit` is for literal values. columns should be specified using `col` or just the name. `lit('mydate')` does not reference your column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is almost correct.

If you have a dataframe with timestamps in string.

```
+--------------------+
|             strDate|
+--------------------+
|26/Feb/2023:13:30:16|
|26/Feb/2023:13:05:37|
+--------------------+
```

You convert the column of 'strDate' to the given format.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

res = df.select(F.to_timestamp(F.col('strDate'),"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss")).show()
res.show()
```

Yields

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|to_timestamp(strDate, dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss)|
+-------------------------------------------+
|                        2023-02-26 13:30:16|
|                        2023-02-26 13:05:37|
+-------------------------------------------+
```

We can verify the datatype with
`res.dtypes`

```
res.dtypes

Out[28]: [('to_timestamp(strDate, dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss)', 'timestamp')]
```